# I was wondering how I could add buttons in processing to replace my keyPressed for gameStates

Tags: processing

I was wondering how I could make a button in processing to replace my keyPressed commands, I'd just like to make it a little more asthetically pleasing. The reason why I'm asking how to build the button is because I don't know what I should do in order to build the button that can be usable for the diffrent gameStates that I made. If I can get any help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
PImage background, backgroundGameState1, headbasketballbackground, player1, player2;
boolean moveRight, moveLeft, moveRight2, moveLeft2;
int canvasSizeX= 1000;
int canvasSizeY = 600;
int mainBackgroundX = 1000;
int mainBackgroundY = 600;
int gameState1 = 1;
int player1X = 100;
int player1Y = 200;
int player2X = 100;
int player2Y = 200;
int backgroundGameState1X= 1000;
int backgroundGameState1Y=600;
int time;
int player1MovmentX = 700;
int player2MovmentX = 100;
PVector Position = new PVector(500, 400);
PVector Velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
PVector Acceleration = new PVector(0, 2);
float elasticity = 0.8;
float airResistance = 0;

void setup() {
  //size of canvas is 1000 on the X-axis by 600 on the y-axis
  size(1000, 600);
  //Loaded images and called them, also made sure to resize them in order to match the canvas size or to make program more asthetically pleasing
  background = loadImage("headbasketballbackground.png");
  background.resize(mainBackgroundX, mainBackgroundY);
  backgroundGameState1 = loadImage("backgroundgamestate1.png");
  backgroundGameState1.resize(backgroundGameState1X, backgroundGameState1Y);
  player1 = loadImage("steph.png");
  //resized image for the steph curry png
  player1.resize(player1X, player1Y);
  player2 = loadImage("kobe.png");
  //resized the png
  player2.resize(player2X, player2Y);

  time=millis();
}

void draw() {
  if (gameState1 == 1) {
    background(backgroundGameState1);
    if (millis() > time + 1000) {
      text("Click On Space To Enter The Game!", 100, 100);
      textSize(50);
      textSize(40);
      text("Click on 'h' or 'H' to access the how to play page!",10,200);
      
      // delay(3000); Used as a test to see how the  delay would work and found it to be extremely slow so I increased it to 1000 milliseconds
    }
    drawGameState1();
  }     
  if (gameState1 == 0) {
    background(0, 0, 0);
    String howToPlay = "How to play Head Basketball Remake";
    textSize(36);
    text(howToPlay, 200, 100);
    rect(490, 150, 10, 400);
    textSize(24);
    text("Player 1", 190, 170);
    text("Player 2", 690, 170);
    text("Click on a to move left", 120, 230);
    text("Click on d to move right", 120, 330);
    text("Click on the left arrow key to move left", 530, 230);
    text("Click on the right arrow key to move right", 510, 330);
    //text("");
    //text();
  }
  if (gameState1 == 2) {
    background(background);
    image(player1, player1MovmentX, 300);
    image(player2, player2MovmentX, 300);
    drawGameState2();
  } 
  if (player1MovmentX < 30) {
    player1MovmentX = 30;
  }
  if (player1MovmentX > 850) {
    player1MovmentX = 850;
  }
  if ( player2MovmentX < 30) {
    player2MovmentX = 30;
  }
  if (player2MovmentX > 850) {
    player2MovmentX = 850;
  }

  //  if (gameState2 == 3) {
  //  text("Congrats you won!");
  //}
}
void drawGameState() {
}
void drawGameState1() {
}
void drawGameState2() {
  drawBall();
  checkIfBallHitEdge();
  moveBall();
  drawPlayer1Movment();
  drawPlayer2Movment(); 
}
void drawGameState3() {
}
void drawPlayer1Movment() {
  if (moveRight) {
    player1MovmentX += 10;
  }
  if (moveLeft) {
    player1MovmentX -= 10;
  }
}
void drawPlayer2Movment() {
  if (moveRight2) {
    player2MovmentX += 10;
  }
  if (moveLeft2) {
    player2MovmentX -= 10;
  }
}

//pvectors used here
void drawBall() {
  ellipse(Position.x, Position.y, 30, 30);
  fill(0,0,0);
}

void moveBall() {
  Velocity = Velocity.add(Acceleration);
  Velocity = Velocity.mult((0.9-airResistance)); // This slows the ball down a little bit each instant
  Position = Position.add(Velocity);
}
//pvectors end here

void checkIfBallHitEdge() {
  if (Position.x < 0 || Position.x > width) {
    Velocity.x *= -1;
  }
  if (Position.y < 100) {
    Velocity.y *= -1;
  }
  if (Position.y > height-150) { // Strikes the ground
    Velocity.y *= -elasticity;
    Position.y = height-150;
    
  }
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (gameState1 == 1) {
    if (keyCode == 32) {
      gameState1 = 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == 72) {
      gameState1 = 0;
    }
  } else if (gameState1 == 2) {
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      moveRight = true;
    }
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      moveLeft = true;
    }
    if (keyCode == 68) {
      moveRight2 = true;
    }
    if (keyCode == 65) {
      moveLeft2 = true;
    }
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      Velocity.y = -70;
    }
  }
}


void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    moveRight = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    moveLeft = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == 68) {
    moveRight2 = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == 65) {
    moveLeft2 = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [GUI library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/#gui) like [ControlP5](https://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) to get buttons (and other controls) to use in your project.

Otherwise, the general approach would be to draw a rectangle, then check to see if the `mouseX` and `mouseY` coordinates are within the rectangle when the mouse is clicked.

If you need a more detailed answer, you could try asking a more specific question with a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the specific problem you're trying to solve.